# How to link Jquery files in Joomla 3x to head section

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

How to link jquery files in Joomla 3x to head section. I also downloaded and installed plugin "jQuery++ Integrator by tushev.org", But this is not going to work for me. I am trying this for a image slider. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Similar answer here by @Lodder http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2486/how-to-use-additional-jquery-ui-libraries-such-as-draggable

Answer (score 2):

Joomla 3 actually ships with a jQuery version core. Using other jQuery versions likely only generates conflicts. So you should use the one which comes with Joomla whenever possible.

To load it you should use the command `JHtmlJquery::framework()` (See http://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtmlJquery.html#method_framework). This will load it into the head in "noConflict" mode and makes sure it's only loaded once, even when requested by multiple extensions.

In your case, I would use this code:

```
JHtmlJquery::framework(); 
JHtml::script('com_yourcomponent/jssor.core.js', false, true);
JHtml::script('com_yourcomponent/jssor.utils.js', false, true);
JHtml::script('com_yourcomponent/jssor.slider.js', false, true);
JHtml::script('com_yourcomponent/slide.js', false, true);
```

Then put your files into following locations:

- /media/com_yourcomponent/js/jssor.core.js
- /media/com_yourcomponent/js/jssor.utils.js
- /media/com_yourcomponent/js/jssor.slider.js
- /media/com_yourcomponent/js/slide.js

Doing it this way will even allow the template to override specific files if needed.
See the excellent blog post from Michael Babker for more details: http://www.babdev.com/blog/139-use-the-media-folder-allow-overridable-media

Comment: Thanks for Reply

But this is not working for me.
I added Jquery links in header section as below :

<?php
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
JHtml::script(JUri::base() . '/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js', true);
JHtml::script(JUri::base() . '/js/jssor.core.js', true);
JHtml::script(JUri::base() . '/js/jssor.utils.js', true);
JHtml::script(JUri::base() . '/js/jssor.slider.js', true);
JHtml::script(JUri::base() . '/js/slide.js', true);
?>

Can you please tell me any mistakes here

Thanks

Comment: Why are you loading jquery-1.9.1? With this, you're loading two versions of jQuery, the one from core and an own one.
Also, are you storing your JS in www.example.com/js/file.js?

Comment: Can you please suggest me proper syntax for this. Since I don't have any knowledge of Jquery and PHP.

Comment: Added example code

Comment: JInstaller: :Install: File does not exist C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla30\tmp\install_5412b34a54809\Wkl-Joomla\media\js

When I tested with above syntax, above error is displaying but it installing the template but slider is not working. Can you please make out where the problem is.

Comment: I am using media tag to add the folders                            
<media folder="media" destination="com_yourcomponent">
            <folder>js</folder>
   <folder>css</folder>
  <folder>images</folder>
  </media>

Comment: The way you try to add the media files means you need to have them in your installation zip in /media/js, /media/css and /media/images. You likely don't have the files stored there.

Comment: I solved this problem with   "<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>"   I am very thankful to you for your effort on helping me to find solution.

Comment: Please, just don't do that. DON'T LOAD YOUR OWN JQUERY VERSION!